# Logging a user in manually on Laravel 5

Tags: php, facebook, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I'm using facebook JS to log in users to a laravel 5 application.
I'm able to add the information to the database correctly but I'm trying to log the user in manually and can't figure it out.

Here is my controller:

```
    <?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\lib\TopAdditions;
use App\Http\lib\GeneralFunctions;
use App\User;

class FacebookLoginController extends Controller{
    public function FacebookRegistration(){


        $facebook = new User();
        $isThereAUser = User::where('name', $_GET['name'])->get();

        if(!count($isThereAUser) > 0){
            $facebook->name = $_GET['name'];
            $facebook->email = $_GET['email'];
            $facebook->password = sha1($_GET['password']);
            $facebook->remember_token = $_GET['token'];
            $facebook->save();

            $id = User::where('name', $_GET['name'])->get();
            $this->LoginUser($id);

        }

    }

    public function LoginUser($id){

        \Auth::login($id[0]['id'],true);



    }
}
```

When I run that and there is no such user in the database, the user is created and I get this message when the manual login is attempted:

> ErrorException in Guard.php line 425:
>   Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, integer given

I've been searching the web for similar situations but couldn't find anything that will help...

Please help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass the user object, not the id, to `Auth::login`. So just change your function to be like this:

```
public function LoginUser($user){
    \Auth::login($user, true);
}
```

Comment: by $user I'm assuming you mean like this? $user = User::where('name', $_GET['name'])->get(); ?? If so, doesn't work... I get the message: "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given"

Comment: It should be `$user = User::where('name', $_GET['name'])->first();` in order to get the user object, otherwise you get a collection :)

Comment: Just did, it wanted me to wait 2 minutes :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this is the solution that worked for me in Laravel 5.4:

```
public function LoginUser($id){
    $user = User::find($id);
    auth()->login($user);
}
```